# C++ Calculating the number of bytes in an array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets

This may or may not be a very simple question, but I would like to know what function to call in order to figure out how many bytes are in an array at any given time.  For example, how would I know what to put as the third argument in the send command in the code below?

```
int *array= new int[500];
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));

//newsockfd is declared elsewhere in the code
send(newsockfd, array, _______, 0);
```

Comment: `sizeof(array)` will return 4 or 8 and that's not what you want. Read a comparison of pointers and arrays. **Now.**

Comment: That `memset` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  The short answer is that you have to keep track of the size yourself.

Comment: With memset all I'm trying to do is to put 0 in every place.  Is it doing that correctly?

Comment: H2CO3, care to share what I should do instead to fill it with 0's?

Comment: `memset(array, 0, 500*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Or some people prefer `memset(array, 0, 500*sizeof array[0]);` since that would work even if you changed the type of the array. But the bottom line is that you have to tell memset that there's 500 elements in your array.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) anyone?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley LOL, you are funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of an array is constant (it's just a hunk of memory).

You'll need to keep track of how many elements of the array are valid yourself, in a separate variable.

As others have noted, the last argument to `memset` should be the number of bytes you want set to 0 -- but `array` is just a pointer, so `sizeof(array)` will yield only 4 (or 8 on a 64-bit platform). Again, you'll need to manually pass in `sizeof(int) * 500` (or use a constant for the 500 so you don't have to update the number in multiple places if it changes).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that you can get count of items that dynamically allocated for an array, so the line `memset(array, 0, sizeof(array))` do not fill 500 items in array with 0, and `sizeof(array)` is always equal to `sizeof(int*)`, so if you want to have access to count of items that allocated for an array, you should either use a separate value that contain the size or use C++ storages like `std::vector`

Answer (score 2):

Your `memset()` doesn't clear the dynamicly allocated memory `new int[500]`, but just the first `sizeof(int*)` bytes.

If you want to clear the heap memory, do it this way:

```
memset(array, 0, 500 * sizeof(int));
```

or at initialization time:

```
int *array= new int[500]();
```

Comment: The original code would not change the pointer `array`.  It would set the first `sizeof(int*)` bytes in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/) is a good reading about the subject (not directly about the sizeof() operator but handling arrays in C++ in general, in a proper "C++ way").